# C# How to save an enum type to each structure in a structure array

Tags: c#, struct, enums

I'm having a problem checking out each type of structure in repeating mode.

```
private static MyStruct myStruct;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myStruct = new MyStruct[3]

    myStruct[0].OptionType = OptionType.Type00;
    myStruct[0].Type.Type00.Value00 = 5;
    myStruct[0].Type.Type00.Value01 = 10;

    myStruct[1].OptionType = OptionType.Type01;
    myStruct[1].Type.Type01.Value00 = 4;
    myStruct[1].Type.Type01.Value01 = 8;

    myStruct[2].Type.OptionType = OptionType.Type01;
    myStruct[2].Type.Type01.Value00 = 6;
    myStruct[2].Type.Type01.Value01 = 3;
}

private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myStruct.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (myStruct[i].OptionType)
        {
            case OptionType.Type00:
            Console.WriteLine($"Value00 = {myStruct[i].Type.Type00.Value00} Value01 = {myStruct[i].Type.Type00.Value01}");
            break;
            case OptionType.Type01:
            Console.WriteLine($"Value00 = {myStruct[i].Type.Type01.Value00} Value01 = {myStruct[i].Type.Type01.Value01}");
            break;
        }
            //error
            //if (i == 2)
                //i = 0; //Repeat.

            //solution
            if (i == 2)
                i = -1; //Repeat.
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    internal OptionType OptionType;
    internal Type Type;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct Type
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal Type00 Type00;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal Type01 Type01;
}

[Flags]
internal enum OptionType : uint
{
    Type00 = 0,
    Type01 = 1,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Type00
{
    internal int Value00;
    internal int Value01;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Type01
{
    internal int Value00;
    internal int Value01;
}
```

1 ° Output:

Value00 = 5, Value01 = 10;

Value00 = 4, Value01 = 8;

Value00 = 6, Value01 = 3;

2°, 3°... Output after repetitions:

Value00 = 4, Value01 = 8;

Value00 = 6, Value01 = 3;

In

```
myStruct[0].Type.Type00.Value00 and myStruct[0].Type.Type00.Value01
```

The values passed remain the same.

But in

```
myStruct[0].OptionType, the passed value of OptionType.Type00
```

Changes to OptionType.Type01;

Why does it happen? How can we make it stay the same value as before?

Comment: `internal Type02 Type01;` I can't see a declaration for `Type02`. Is that a type0?

Comment: I've replicated your code and I can't see the value of OptionType changing. Where do you think it changes?

Comment: Corrected, it is internal Type01 Type01;

Comment: You're still not showing where in the code you think the value of OptionType changes. Are you asking why subsequent runs only have two repetitions?

Comment: It has only two reps, because somehow, myStruct [0] .OptionType = OptionType.Type00
Changes to myStruct [0] .OptionType = OptionType.Type01
And then when the loop repeats, it will be false.

Comment: That's not why the example code has only two reps, it has two reps because you are setting i to 0 which is then incremented to 1 by the for loop and so the first element in the array is skipped. If it was actually changing the value of OptionType it would still print a line just with 0 as the two values.

Comment: Lol, that's right, I just tested. Answer and I will mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code repeats with two repetitions because you are setting `i` to 0 which is then incremented to 1 by the for loop and so the first element in the array is skipped. If it was actually changing the value of `OptionType` it would still print a line just with 0 as the two values.